Does the connection pool exist on the SurrealDB Python SDK?
I'm trying to use Python SDK from SurrealDB, do you support a connection pool or do I need to implement it myself?
First, I referred to the official documentation and then searched for various libraries for about 2 days, but couldn't find any suitable connection pool implementation.

If the documentation doesn't say it implements a connection pool, there's no reason to think it does. So you'll need to do it yourself.
